# Parentheses verification issue

Tags: vb.net, algorithm, parentheses

I'm writing a simple calculator app, before evaluating a statement, it checks to make sure that any parentheses are formatted correctly. It initially checks that there is the same amount of opening `(` and closing `)` parentheses. And if there are, then it will check that they are in the correct order.

unlike this: `6) / (1 + 4)8 + (5`.

In order to that I used this code:

`Chkp("(1+1/2)+(2+3)")`

which would call:

```
Function ChkP(text As String)
    For i As Integer = 0 To CountOf(text, "(") - 1
        If CharIndex(text, "(", i) > CharIndex(text, ")", i) Then Return False
    Next
    Return True
End Function
```

which would then call:

```
Function CharIndex(text As String, character As String, ByRef index As Integer)
    For x As Integer = 0 To text.Length - 1
        If text(x) = character Then
            index -= 1
            If index = -1 Then
                Return x
            End If
        End If
    Next
    Return -1
End Function
```

If `Chkp` should return `False` the parentheses are wrong otherwise they are correct, however, the output is always that the parentheses are invalid, even if the are correct.

Is there a way to fix this? Or is there just a better way of checking parentheses altogether?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you need this to check for problems like `1 (+) 2`, or will that be checked at a later stage?

Comment: @TedHopp It will be checked at a later stage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest approach to check that parentheses are balanced and a close parenthesis always comes after a corresponding open parenthesis is:

1. Initialize a nesting level variable to 0.
2. For each character of the text: if the character is `'('`, add 1 to the nesting level; if the character is `')'`, then subtract 1 from the nesting level and if the nesting level is then negative, immediately report failure.
3. At the end, report success if and only if the nesting level is 0.